# What is a "MFC Dialog Extension"? (Windows/C++ novice - Linux background)

Tags: c++, windows

I am working with a Windows C++ API which mentions MFC Dialog Extension.

What is an MFC Dialog Extension?

I have always used Linux and the resources I found online were confusing.

Comment: Did you mean [MFC extension DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f7ck28.aspx)? If you are going down the WinAPI or even MFC route you might want to reconsider that and explore other options for GUI.

Comment: Yes that's the one. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC Dialog extension is using to create GUI(s) using drag and drop options which are available in the visual studio